# Библиотека с плеером

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

Посоветуйте библиотеку для проигрывания видео и аудио, если такая существует?

Comment: libvlc можно попробовать

Comment: avfoundation попробуйте

Comment: Воспользовался `AVPlayer`, но там голый интерфейс, может кто посоветует оболочку для проигрывателя, кнопки стоп,плей и скрол рабочий, что бы можно было с любого места начать просмотр ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел хорошую библиотеку, стандартный `AVPlayer` + Банальный интерфейс без лишнего.
https://github.com/mzds/AVPlayerDemo

Answer (score 0):

Есть стандартный класс [AVPlayerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/)